# Plot is wrong for oscillating function

Tags: plotting

It doesnt even oscillate that much

```
Plot[Exp[-Pi x^2 + I ( 60 1/(x^2 + .6) + 0.2)] // Re, {x, -2, 2}, 
 PlotRange -> Full, MaxRecursion -> 15]
```

[image]

What is wrong? How to fix?

Comment: Try adding `PlotPoints -> 100` or the like

Comment: Yup, did the trick.

Comment: I voted your question as a duplicate of the one linked, because it is the same issue with the same solution, regardless of the function in that case being `ParametricPlot` while the one here is just `Plot`. Please see also the questions referenced in the proposed duplicate question for additional details. To put it briefly: the correct thing to do is to use the (unfortunately undocumented) option `Method -> {Refinement -> {ControlValue -> (*angle in radians*) }}`, with a suitably small angle. Since this is the root of the problem, adding sampling points will not necessarily help.